# Is return statement required in below code of javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var Greeting = (function () {
    function Greeting() {
    }
    Greeting.prototype.greet = function () {
      console.log("Hello World!!!");
    };
  return Greeting;
    }());

var obj = new Greeting();
obj.greet()
```

If I remove return statement it says obj.greet() is not a function.

Comment: Yes, it is required, otherwise `Greeting` will be `undefined`

Comment: Below code gives me same results because internally it creates a constructor,When I explicitly write a constructor,It expects a return statement , Can it be explained in detail please                                     
 var Greeting = (function () {
 
    Greeting.prototype.greet = function () {
      console.log("Hello World!!!");
    };
 
    }());

var obj = new Greeting();
obj.greet()

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is required because you have created a "private" scope.

```
// GlobalScope: You create a variable named `Greeting`
var Greeting = (function() {
    // PrivateScope: You create a function named `Greeting`
    function Greeting() {}

    // PrivateScope: You create a method on the Greeting prototype
    Greeting.prototype.greet = function() {
        console.log("Hello World!!!");
    };

    // PrivateScope: You tell your function to return your "private" scoped `Greeting`
    return Greeting;
}());
```

You can express the same code without having a "private" scope, and then you will not need the `return` statement.

```
function Greeting() {}

Greeting.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log("Hello World!!!");
};

var obj = new Greeting();
obj.greet()
```

Comment: Asking this question because here because didnt get answer for a long time ,Please help !!!! html5 input slider is using mousemove events as I checked in dev tools performance . My problem is mouse move stucks while sliding because set intervals is triggering in between, whose delay is very less. Ideally these setinterval functions are written to capture user's interactions on website. Is there a way to avoid setintervals while sliding ??.